# How to check UITextField is not blank in Swift 2.0? Is there better way to count the string?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am try to check textfield is blank or not and what I am trying is

```
if(EmailTextField.text.characters.count>0)
{
}
```

but I can't use relation operator on this count method. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By extension... To ensure that its not even take any blank spaces...

```
extension String {

var isBlank: Bool {
       get {
            let trimmed = stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
            return trimmed.isEmpty
        }
   }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if !EmailTextField.text!.isBlank{
   //TextField is not blank
}
```

Comment: where should i wrote this code? pls help me

Comment: at the end of class write extension...

Comment: if i want it to access globally? can i?

Comment: if((cell.txtEmail.text?.isBlank) != nil)

Comment: plz update your answer for nil check explicitly.. may be required in swift

Comment: if this question helpful for others plz upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `String`'s `isEmpty` property:

```
//if EmailTextField is a UITextField instance 
if EmailTextField.text != nil && !EmailTextField.text!.isEmpty {

}

if let text = EmailTextField.text where !text.isEmpty {

}
```

Comment: if(!EmailTextField.text.isEmpty != nil){

Comment: actually it is `(a.text != nil && !a.text!.isEmpty)`, but I updating my answer